# Can Transformers detect each other even in their alt-modes?

Tags: transformers, transformers-2007

In the *Transformers* film, Ratchet and Bumblebee noticed that the F22 was not a friendly and instead, was Starscream. Can all Transformers detect other Transformers even if they are in their alt-modes?

Comment: I don't believe they can, like when they were searching for Jetfire.  They walked right up on him and it wasn't until they saw the symbol they realized he was a Decepticon at one time.. Optimus changed from his blue truck, to the old beat up one to get away from Lockdown.

Comment: That could be explained by the fact that he was in a sort of "hibernate" mode... But other than that...

Comment: In Transformers Generation 1 in the episode “Red Alert” the Autobots find a police car they think is an Autobot named Red Alert, and they were talking to it and shaking it until a policeman told them off, and they realised it was a normal car. Posting as a comment because it’s not from the live action movies.

Answer (score 2):

As far as we know, *no*. Although if they're observant they may notice details, like Decepticon badges other non-Earth details or things out of place, such as "TO PUNISH AND ENSLAVE" instead of "TO PROTECT AND SERVE" on the side of the police vehicle.

In *Dark of the Moon* we see that the N.E.S.T. base has energon detectors installed, to alert them of incoming Transformers, especially Decepticons. This helps illustrate that the Autobots being present, on their own, was not enough of a warning. It's not clear evidence, but it's just another piece of the world that adds up to alt mode being effective camouflage to other Cybertronians.